# Is it possible to make this image in SVG responsive?

Tags: html, svg

I have been trying a few things with this piece of code for the show image on click effect.

```
<section transform="translate(0 464)" style="width:1000px;height: 700px;">
    <section transform="translate(0 0)" style="width:1000px;height: 700px;">
        <img style="width:1000px;height: 700px;" src="!IMAGESORCE!" alt="">
    </section>
    <svg transform="translate(0 -700)" style="width:1000px;height: 700px;">
        <rect  x="0" y="0" width="1000px" height="700px" style="fill: #fff;">
         <animate id="op1" attributename="opacity" begin="click"  dur="2s"  from="1"  to="0" fill="freeze" repeatCount= "1"></animate>
         <animate attributename="x" begin="op1.end" dur=".1s"  from="0"  to="-1000px" fill="freeze" repeatCount= "1"></animate>
        </rect>
    </svg>
</section>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to make the image fit the width automatically while keeping it work without any JavaScript.

If I wish to do something like `style="width:100%;height: auto;"`, what should i change `transform="translate(0 -700)"` to?

Please help if you could. Thank you!

Comment: give it a viewBox

Comment: Instead of using `width` and `height` (`style="width:1000px;height: 700px;"`) use a `viewBox` attribute like so: `<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 700">`. If an svg element has no declared width and height but has a viewBox attribute will take all the width available, i.e the width of the parent element

Comment: thank you! I looked. The height still needs to roughly match the ratio( If i understood right) It seems there is really a way to make responsive the way i was wishing ╥﹏╥...